# Google sheet script to delete row if certain cells are empty and add row at the bottom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with a table with content in the range B6:Y1000.
I would like a script that would delete all rows if column C-D-E-F-G are empty.
I also need that this script add 5 new rows at the bottom after the last row with content in column C-D-E-F-G.
All the added rows have to contain formulas.
The added rows make it possible for me to continue filling the table, because the first function deletes all the rows.
This is my sheet:

[My Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CPcMx3Dhbqi-zO4D3jYNxO-PGjyW3iTfRo5gRmEB9p4/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a biref description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function removeEmpty() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Suivi Clients');
  const empty_rows = [];
  const lastRow = sh.getLastRow()
  Browser.msgBox(lastRow)
  const data = sh.getRange("C6:G" + lastRow).getValues();
  for (var i in data) if (data[i].join('') == '') empty_rows.push(+i + 6);
  empty_rows.reverse().forEach(x => sh.deleteRow(x));
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lastRow - empty_rows.length, 5)

  var rng = sh.getRange('A6:Z6')
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('A' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':Z' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);

  // H-I-J-K-L
  var rng = sh.getRange('H' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length) + ':L' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length))
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('H' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':L' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  // O
  var rng = sh.getRange('O' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length) + ':O' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length))
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('O' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':O' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  // Q-R-S-T-U
  var rng = sh.getRange('Q' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length) + ':U' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length))
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('Q' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':U' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  // X-Y 
  var rng = sh.getRange('X' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length) + ':Y' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length))
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('X' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':Y' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);

}
```

Comment: Mike, thank you for your insight. It work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

#### Delete Rows

```
function drows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  let d = 0;
  sh.getRange("B6:Y1000").getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!r[2] && !r[3] && !r[4] && !r[5] && !r[6]) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 6 - d++);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly to delete rows.
But at the bottom, I would like to have 5 lines containing the formulas so that I can continue to add customers. is it possible?

Comment: Please provide the formulas that you want

Comment: All formulas are in my sheets in all colorized columns

Comment: I don't follow links to spreadsheets. Please post all required information in the question.

Comment: I would just like there to be 5 blank rows at the very bottom after the last row containing values in columns C-D-E-F and G. The formulas are in columns B-H-I-J-K-L-O-Q-R-S-T-U-X and Y. So extend 5 rows with the content of these columns